# Парсинг JSON (JObject) с динамическим элементом внутри ответа

Tags: c#, json, парсер

не могу понять как правильно получить данные из JSON вида (укорочен для простоты чтения):

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "registrators": {
    "6594192": {
      "id": 6594192,
      "name": "",
      "channel": "electro_event_log",
      "unit_id": "-",
      "offset": 0.0,
      "modem_id": "7a6886",
}
```

Где children-массив (в данном случае 6594192) динамический, т.е. заранее id неизвестен.
Необходимо передать значение modem_id в переменную, но указать стандартный путь до него ["registrators"][0]["modem_id"] не получится. Предполагаю, что необходимо сделать цикл foreach, но как правильно задать тело цикла понять не могу.
Для парсинга использую NewtonSoft. Заранее спасибо

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Registrator>`, где `Registrator` - класс, представляющий данные внутри этого id. А стройковый ключ словаря - сам id.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за Ваш ответ.
Сделал: 
`var gvresult = JObject.Parse(gvresponse.Content);
                Dictionary<string, Registrators> getValues = gvresult.ToObject<Dictionary<string, Registrators>>();`
Но, поскольку, первым членом JSON является status, получаю: "Error converting value "ok" to type 'Program.Registrators'. Path 'status', line 1, position 14."
Сам класс: 
` public class Registrators
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string channel { get; set; }` и т.д.

Comment: Отлично, теперь создайте класс `Response`, и 2 свойства в нем, первый `string status`, второй - тот самый словарь. И десерализуйте в него.

Comment: @aepot не совсем понимаю как правильно десериализовать, в большинстве способов получаю аналогичную ошибку.
Класс ответа:
 'public class RegResponse
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Registrators> getValues { get; set; }
    }'

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос и доведите JSON в вопросе да валидного состояния. То что он обрезан, это понятно, но сделайте так, чтобы его можно было десереализовать без ошибок. И вам модератор прикрепил ссылку вверху вопроса, смотрели там?

Comment: @aepot полный ответ JSON — [тут](https://app.quicktype.io/?share=MMcFud7d8pCi3AC54auy) поскольку не влезает в рамки комментария.
Информацию по ссылке изучил и примерно так и делаю. Основная проблем в том, что json не десериализуется в словарь с различными исключениями типа format exception

Comment: 1) Удалите класс `Registrators` 2) переименуйте класс `The102186` в `Registrator` 3) `public Registrators Registrators { get; set; }` замените на `public Dictionary<string, Registrator> Registrators { get; set; }` 4) `Value[]` замените на `List<Value>`